# Error initializing JVM

Tags: jvm, sap-commerce-cloud

I am getting "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" error when I am trying to start hybris server. 
I have set 
`wrapper.java.additional.1=-Xmx1G
wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M`
My machine is 64 bit 8GB RAM Windows

Comment: Why do you even want to set PermSize to 1GB?

Comment: Decrease your PermSize and retry (512m)

Comment: @mp911de Initially it was 512m. It didnt work . hence i changed it. Error I am getting is`Launching a JVM...
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: @javaUser do you have at least 2gb o free memory in your system?

Comment: @Jakub Kubrynski I have 6Gb memory free

Comment: And what error do you get if you set PermSize to 512m?

Comment: I am getting same error

Comment: @Jakub Kubrynski This conf worked  `wrapper.java.additional.1=-512m wrapper.java.additional.2=-XX:MaxPermSize=512M`  Thanks

Comment: @javaUser it is exactly the same configuration you've posted in your question?

Comment: It was a typo. I edited :)

Comment: Erm, do you use as well a 64bit JavaVM?

Answer (score 1):

1. I faced the same problem once, The problem in my case was that too many other Applications were running on my system.
   So go to the task manager and check the memory available use.
   Close some applications and try running.

   2. Also if you are using eclipse Then, In your eclipse.ini file (this is beside the eclipse executable), replace -Xmx256m with -Xmx1024m (or Xmx512m).
      This is not compulsory but in certain cases it works.
   3. If you are using some extension then,

Open YOURPATH/config/local.properties file.

Add the following entry:
config/local.properties

> build.parallel=true

Save the file.
(*In cases where we have multiple cores in the machine, we can tell hybris to utilize these by building in parallel and in certain cases this too works)*

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same probelm. I followed below steps and set the max heap size to 1GB.

1. Add the following content to local.properties

tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx4G -ea -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_init_tomcat.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}"

2. ant clean all
3. start hybrisserver

Reference
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0002437669